# Visual Studio Code and Git get my IP blocked on my NAS

Tags: git, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ssh, synology

I don't know if this is an issue with Visual Studio Code or Ubuntu or Git or SSH or Synology. Therefor I am asking this question here, on the site I consider to be the jack of all trades.

I have a Ubuntu desktop PC and a Synology NAS (operating system is DSM). I have installed Git server on the NAS. On the PC I have a private programming hobby project which uses Git. I have a bare-repo on the NAS which acts as a Git remote for the project. The remote was added with the command `git remote add origin ssh://gituser@192.168.XXX.XXX:/path/to/remote/repository/name.git`. I have created a private-public key on the PC and the public-key has been moved to the NAS to path `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the gituser.

On the PC, if I manually `cd` my way into the Git-project folder and use `git push`, then the remote server asks me my Synology password, I enter it, press ENTER and everything works. I can also clone the remote to another location on my PC and it works.

However, if I launch Visual Studio Code and open the project as a folder, then I get very quickly IP-banned by the Synology NAS due to exceeding the maximum allowed amount of failurous login attemps.

So the question is: What is going wrong here and how do I make it work?

I am guessing this happens because VSCode tries to fetch possible updates from the remote automatically but fails to do so because DSM demands a password. I tried to add the line `PasswordAuthentication no` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the NAS but this didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did manage to make everything work. I'm not sure what it was that finally solved this but what I did:

### On my Synology NAS

I decided to use my admin account for the Git remote connection.

I used `sudo chmod 700` on `/volume1/homes/adminaccount` and `/volume1/homes/adminaccount/.ssh/` and `/volume1/homes/adminaccount/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and unommented `#PubkeyAuthentication yes` and `#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys`

### On my Ubuntu PC

I edited my `~/.ssh/config` and it looks like this now:

```
# My NAS
Host 192.168.XXX.XXX
  Port 12345
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myrsakey
```

### Result

Everything seem to work. I can start Visual Studio Code, work on the project and push to the remote without getting my IP banned.

Thank you @VonC for guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

First, try with an SSH URL like:

```
 ssh://gituser@192.168.XXX.XXX/path/to/remote/repository/name.git
                            ^^^
                            no ':' if you are using ssh://
```

Second, make sure your key has no passphrase (`ssh-keygen -P "" ...`)

Third, if it has no passphrase, then it should not ask for a remote user password: double-check the content of `~gituser/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and verify the public key has been copied in full, as *one* line (not multiple lines)

Once the command-line works without asking password, then you can test it with VSCode.

Comment: @WaitoPiggu Does `ssh gituser@192.168.XXX.XXX` work? As long as a basic SSH connection does not work, no git command will.

Comment: I removed the password from my private rsa key located in `~/.ssh/myrsakey` on my PC.

I checked and myrsakey.pub has been copied to /volume1/homes/gituser/.ssh/authorized:_keys correctly in one row.

I still got asked for the password though.

Comment: @WaitoPiggu That is because the private key is not use. Your solution with ~/.ssh/config will work indeed.

Comment: I also realized I could've gone around this problem by editing the settings of Visual Studio Code and disable auto fetch. That would still require me to enter the password of the admin account of my NAS though.